# Chaining multiple ajax requests with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, rsvp.js

I'm looking to chain multiple ajax requests, something along the lines of:
get first JSON, if successful move on and get second JSON, if successful make a new object consisting of both JSON data.

```
// get first json
$.getJSON('http://www.json1.com').then(function(json1){
    return json1
}).then(function(json1){
    // get second json
    $.getJSON('http://www.json2.com').then(function(json2){
        var both = {}
        both.one = json1
        both.two = json2
        return both
    })
})
```

Should I be nesting `.then` statements in each other? I'm not completely sure how to get the `both` variable.

Comment: is it not working? Also, you're using `.then()`, but this doesn't really differ from just using the callback argument. why not just use that instead?

Comment: Hmm, I might not understand the concept correctly. I think I should also be incorporating the `Promise` part as well.

Comment: well in the case like yours, there's no problem doing `$.getJSON('url', function(json1) { $.getJSON('url2', function(json2) { /* work with json1 and json2 */ })});` you would usually use promises when you want to wait for both:

`var p1 = $.getJSON('url1');
 var p2 = $.getJSON('url2');
 $.when(p1,p2).then(function(json1,json2) { /* do something */});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> .then(function(json1){
>     return json1
> })
> ```

That's an unnecessary, (nearly) identity call.

> ```
> .then(function(json1){
>      …;
> ```

You should always `return` from a `then` callback, so that the new promise gets a value. You can even return promises, which will be "unwrapped"!

> Should I be nesting .then statements in each other?

It doesn't really matter whether you nest them or chain them, that's [the great thing about promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572). Chaining them reduces the height of your "pyramid", so it is considered cleaner, however you cannot access the variables from higher scopes. In your case, you need to access `json1`, so you have to nest them.

> I'm not completely sure how to get the both variable.

When you do `return` from the callbacks, you can get it as the resolution value of the promise that you get back from the `then` call.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.json1.com').then(function(json1){
    return $.getJSON('http://www.json2.com').then(function(json2){
        return {one: json1, two: json2};
    })
}).then(function(both) {
    // do something with both!
});
```

Comment: Bergi, you're answer assumes he doesn't want access to `both` outside of the function, which he probably shouldn't, but might.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Your explanation also cleared up a few things for me, thanks!

Comment: Yes he can.  My answer allows for that possibility.

Comment: @Bergi - And barring some compelling evidence to the contrary, I still think my answer is cleaner and more flexible - as long as both is scoped to avoid Mem leaks.

Comment: @user1167442: No, "outside of the callback" implies "is not yet loaded".

Comment: Yeah that's valid.  What mine allows for - and I was probably tunnel visioned when I wrote it because of what I was working on -  is preloading a whole bunch of data and manipulating it before using it at a later time to reduce simultaneous processing load.

Answer (score -3):

I am editing this.  I misstated what the problem is.  The problem is that `both` is defined inside of a function and it is not accessible outside of the function unless you define `both` as an Object outside of the function.  As you have it created, `both` is invisible to the entire world, and the only access to `both` as you have it created is handle it with another deferred callback, but still you don't have a variable defined to hold that Object and more to the point doing it that way would be retarded.

Here is a clean and simple way to accomplish what you want.

```
 var json1=$.getJSON('http://www.json1.com');
 var json2=$.getJSON('http://www.json2.com');
 var both={};

 json1.then(json2).then(function(){
   both.one=json1.responseJSON;
   both.two=json2.responseJSON;
});
```

If you want to be cooler, wrap it in a function and pass the url as an argument.  Just make sure to declare the  `both` object in a scope where you can access it.

Comment: You can `return` from a `then` callback the way he is doing!